# Java - How to do something every time Timer ticks?

Tags: java, timer

I have a java Timer and I want it to do something every time it ticks. For example, I want my program to output this:

Output that I want:

> Tick 1 seconds passed
>   Tick 2 seconds passed
>   Tick 3 seconds passed
>   Tick 4 seconds passed
>   Tick 5 seconds passed
>   Time up, running do_something()...

What I have so far is this:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Time up, running do_something()");
        do_something();
    }
};
timer.schedule(timerTask, 5);
```

Actual Output of my code so far is this:

> Time up, running do_something()...

5 Seconds have passed when I reach this line.

Comment: You'll need a loop in there

Comment: How exactly should I make the loop?

Comment: Well, your `Timer` is setup for a milliseconds delay, so you're only going to get one time, you're going to have to use `schedule(TimerTask, long, long)` if you want it to repeat.  You could also use two `Timer`s, one repeating, one non-repeating set with different intervals. If you want one `Timer`, then you will need to determine when it was first activated, calculate the time between executions and make a determination about what to do. Once you've passed your threshold (i.e. 5 seconds), cancel the timer and do something else

Comment: @cricket_007 If used correctly, a `Timer` is a (kind of) loop

Comment: @Mad Yes, using the other schedule methods.

Comment: I guess I didn't say it clearly at the beginning. I am trying to notify the user about the progress of the timer. So, I need to print the status of the timer every time the timer TICKS. For example, if the Timer ticks from 1000 ms left to 999 ms left, I want to print out the remaining time, like so: "999ms left"

Comment: You can extend the TimerTask to add a field that counts up/down, then. The functional differences between schedule methods are still the same

Comment: For example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32110208/creating-a-count-down-timer-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if your intentions are to loop, you should use the overloaded method of the [`schedule`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long)) over `Timer` as:

```
timer.schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period);
```

which would schedule the specified task for **repeated** fixed-delay execution, beginning after the specified *delay.*